# Whats the difference between toBeInTheDocument and getBy* in @testing-library/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Is there a difference between

```js
expect(screen.queryByText('<something>')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

And

```js
screen.getByText('<something>');
```

(The specific `getBy*` and `queryBy*` operation are not relevant)

In `react-testing-library`?

Comment: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#types-of-queries

You can find the difference in the table on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getByText](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/) tries to find the node and throws an error when it is not able to find it. This will cause the test to fail immediately.

`queryByText` on the other hand will return `null` if it is unable to find the node.

Let's suppose you have text `<something>` in the component that was rendered, you can assert if it has been rendered or not.

If sure that the text has been rendered, then you can simply use `getByText`

```
expect(screen.getByText('<something>')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

and the test would pass.

If for the scenario the text did not render then the above assertion will thrown an error and fail the test case.

In such cases `queryByText` text makes the most sense

**When  has not been rendered**

```
expect(screen.getByText('<something>')).not.toBeInTheDocument(); // throws an error

expect(screen.queryByText('<something>')).not.toBeInTheDocument(); // asserts as true
```

---

[Output comparison](https://gist.github.com/rluvaton/6fb7f344c46246c82d49ee30b359e747)

Comment: So they both provide the same outcome when wanting to know if some element in the document, probably `queryBy*` is better as the assertion error are made to be more readable than thrown errors

Comment: That is correct. `queryByText` is mostly used for the cases when the node is not present in the document but still want to assert the use case.

Comment: So `queryBy*` should be used as it will provide helpful assertion messages in case it fails (although you said that that the mostly used use case is not for that)

Comment: It won't provide assertion messages. But it will allow us to assert for something when something is not present.

Comment: I meant with `toBeInTheDocument`, `queryBy*` by itself is nothing

Comment: I was wrong, `getBy*` gives better error messages, see [here](https://gist.github.com/rluvaton/6fb7f344c46246c82d49ee30b359e747), I think you should include the output/link in your answer for better comparison